# Some of the data is not being fetched

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, ejs

In the page, there's a form that consists of two dropdown lists, blood type, city (city name), and a button. When the button is clicked, information about donors with matching blood type and matching city will appear below the form. In my postgres, there's a good amount of data for a donors table with different types of blood, located in six different cities.

The page displays six default cards showing donors information, and we can clearly see , for example, a donor with blood type AB-, and the city Amman, but when I enter and submit those two values, the page displays a message below the form saying: No donors found.

EJS form

```
<!--start search-->
  <div class="search pt-5 ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="searchBox col-11 rounded-3 shadow p-5 position-relative">
          <form action="donors" method="post" class="d-flex flex-column flex-xl-row gap-3 text-center">   
            <div class=" w-100">
           
              <select name="bloodType" class="form-select form-select-lg" required>
                <option selected hidden style="display:none" value="">Blood Type</option>
                <option value="A+">A+</option>
                <option value="A-">A-</option>
                <option value="B+">B+</option>
                <option value="B-">B-</option>
                <option value="O+">O+</option>
                <option value="O-">O-</option>
                <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class=" w-100">
            <select name="city" class="form-select form-select-lg" required>
                <option selected hidden style="display:none" value="">City</option>
                <option value="amman">Amman</option>
                <option value="madaba">Madaba</option>
                <option value="irbid">Irbid</option>
                <option value="zarqa">Zarqa</option>
                <option value="mafraq">Mafraq</option>
                <option value="ajloun">Ajloun</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="w-100">

            </div>
            <div class=" w-100">

              <!-- <a class="btn searchBtn fw-bold" href="#" type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass fa-lg"></i></a> -->

              <button class="btn searchBtn fw-bold" type="submit">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass fa-lg"></i>
              </button>
              
            </div>
          </form> 
        </div>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  



  
<!--end search-->

<!--start Donors-->



<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <% if (donors && donors.length > 0) { %>
      <% donors.forEach(donor => { %>
          <!-- Render donor card using donor information -->
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
              <!-- customize the donor card layout based on your needs -->
              <div class="card" style="background-color: #D27878;" data-blood-type-index="<%= donor.blood_type %>">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title"><%= donor.full_name %></h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Blood Type: <%= getBloodTypeText(donor.blood_type) %></p>
                      <p class="card-text">City: <%= donor.city_name %></p>
                      <p class="card-text">Phone: <%= donor.phone_number %></p>
                      <!-- add more donor information as needed -->
                  </div>  
              </div>
          </div>
      <% }); %>
  <% } else { %>
      <p>No donors found.</p>
  <% } %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Function in my Node js file:

```
const getBloodTypeText = (bloodType) => {
  // Optionally, you can check if the blood type is one of the expected values
  const validBloodTypes = ['A+', 'A-', 'B+', 'B-', 'O+', 'O-', 'AB+', 'AB-'];
  if (validBloodTypes.includes(bloodType)) {
      return bloodType;
  } else {
    return 'Unknown Blood Type';
  }
};
```

DONORS POST Route

```
app.post('/donors', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const { bloodType, city } = req.body;
      console.log('Blood Type:', bloodType);
      console.log('City:', city);

      let query = 'SELECT * FROM donors WHERE city_name = $1';
      const params = [city];

      if (bloodType) {
          query += ' AND blood_type = $2';
          params.push(bloodType);
      }

      const donorsResult = await db.query(query, params);
      const donors = donorsResult.rows;

      // Render the donors.ejs view
      res.render('donors.ejs', { blood_type: bloodType, city_name: city, donors: donors, getBloodTypeText: getBloodTypeText, getCompatibleBloodTypes: getCompatibleBloodTypes`` });
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```

Donors GET Route

```
app.get('/donors', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Query the database to get distinct blood types
    const bloodTypesResult = await db.query('SELECT DISTINCT blood_type FROM donors');
    const bloodTypes = bloodTypesResult.rows;

    // Query the database to get all cities
    const citiesResult = await db.query('SELECT * FROM city');
    const cities = citiesResult.rows;

    // Query the database to get a default set of 6 donors
    const defaultDonorsResult = await db.query('SELECT * FROM donors LIMIT 6');
    const defaultDonors = defaultDonorsResult.rows;

    // Render the donors.ejs view and pass the blood types, cities, and default donors as variables
    res.render('donors.ejs', { blood_type: bloodTypes, city: cities, donors: defaultDonors, getBloodTypeText: getBloodTypeText, getCompatibleBloodTypes: getCompatibleBloodTypes});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    // Handle other errors if needed
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```

Matching information for donors should appear below, but the page works for the blood type A+, as for the other blood types, the page says: No donors found. Not all blood types or cities work

Comment: If you have a new question you should ask it as a new one instead of vandalizing the previous question, particularly when that one has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Two (possible) errors in your code:

```
SELECT * FROM donors WHERE city_name = amman;
```

Is incorrect, because the city_name should have single quotes, like:

```
SELECT * FROM donors WHERE city_name = 'amman';
```

Secondly, your city name is "Amman", not "amman", so you should do a case insensitive check

```
SELECT * FROM donors WHERE LOWER(city_name) = 'amman';
```

But this may lead to performance problems, so this might be quicker:

```
SELECT * FROM donors WHERE city_name ILIKE 'amman';
```

Because [ILIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#:%7E:text=The%20key%20word%20ILIKE%20can%20be%20used%20instead%20of%20LIKE%20to%20make%20the%20match%20case%2Dinsensitive%20according%20to%20the%20active%20locale.) is doing a case insensitive check.

The SQL of above can be found here: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/q5XoP2Wi)

P.S. The same problem exists for `blood_type`.